# How to fix NPM vulnerabilities (libcipm, libnpm, node-gyp, npm-lifecycle)?

Tags: npm

How should I fix the vulnerabilities below that require manual review ?

```
$ npm --version
6.9.0
$ npm audit fix
up to date in 7.044s
fixed 0 of 4 vulnerabilities in 31604 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
$ npm audit

                       === npm audit security report ===                        

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > libnpm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > node-gyp > tar                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 4 high severity vulnerabilities in 31604 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the *tar* package to version 4.4.2 or later.

Comment: The installed version is 4.4.8 which is the last one.

Comment: How do you know the installed version? What is the output of `npm ls tar`?

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ `npm view tar version` => 4.4.8

Answer (score 1):

This issue solution yet to be release.Many PR open on github regarding the issue.But try this *may* it helps:

```
npm install -D node-gyp
npm install -D tar@">4.4.7"
```

For more details check [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1717).

This issue also [raised](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2036) here.

Attempt to fix [this](https://github.com/npm/node-tar/pull/213) issue.

This might be fixed by **10th May,2019**.

Check [here](https://github.com/fecgov/fec-cms/issues/2821) for more details on it.